# Magento 1.9 - Product page shows blank page

Tags: magento-1.9

Some product detail pages works fine but some product detail page shows blank.System log file shows below error

> 2018-04-30T12:08:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/occasion/public_html/includes/src/Crypt_Hash.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/occasion/public_html/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Seems that you need to run compilation from System -> Tools -> Compilation once.

Comment: Could you pls explain in brief how did you solve the issue, Thanks.

Comment: I am getting the same issue, how can I find what is the issue? There is no console error and log error even view page source also empty.

Comment: In my case the answer of Rehan doesn't work. I just needed to uncomment the 'error_reporting' line to see the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run compilation process.

system -> tools -> Run compilation

Hope this help.